# Bounded sets have finite measure

Tags: measure-theory

Is it in general true that bounded sets have finite measure?
I would like to use this result for an exercise.

Comment: That depends on the measure. For Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}^n$, a bounded measurable set has finite measure. For general measures, the measure of a bounded set can well be infinite.

Comment: For instance, the counting measure on $\mathbb{R}$ has infinite measure for many bounded sets.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As a rather extreme counter example let $X=R^n$ and set $\mu(A)=+\infty$ if $A\subset X$ and $A$ is nonempty and $\mu(\emptyset)=0$, then $\mu$ is a measure which assigns infinite measure to all nonempty subsets (in particular the bounded ones).

On the other hand, the lebesgue measure is finite on all bounded subsets. The amount of work required to show this depends on your definition of a lebesgue measurable set.